# Why my UIViewController can't release when do `po` in the breakPoint

Tags: swift

Present a ViewController. In the method of `viewDidLoad`, it have an array of type `UIViewController`. This array `append` self. If do not `po` the array after append self in the breakpoint, it can run `dealloc` method when it `dismiss` this ViewController. But when do `po` in this time, it can run `dealloc` method. What reason is probable？

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var vcArray: [UIViewController] = []
        vcArray.append(self)
        print("Append End") //breakpoint here , po vcArray
}
```

Create a symbolic breakpoint which symbol is `-[UIViewController dealloc]`

Comment: `dealloc` only works when no one pointing to `ViewController` including itself.

Comment: `dealloc` is working when not go to the breakpoint. Only debug it and `po vcArray`, the method of `dealloc` is not working.